# Setting proxy settings in CURL

Tags: windows, winapi, curl

I am using CURL library to download a file net. I have written a sample in win32. I have few doubts

1)  Why do we need to use CURL. One of my friend says why don’t  we just use win32 API’s to download file.

2)  I have set proxy to my machine. If i try to download the file still it downloads. Is it is not required to set the proxy settings in curl library.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77798327/13513328) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

cURL is a third-party cross-platform library wrapping several commonly used Internet protocols (HTTP, FTP, etc).  You don't HAVE to use it if you don't want to.  It is just one of MANY choices available to developers.  You can certainly use Microsoft's proprietary WinInet API instead if you want to.

Yes, if you use a proxy, you have to configure cURL so it knows about it.  Microsoft uses WinInet in Internet Explorer, and WinInet shares certain settings (like proxies) with all apps that use WinInet, so a WinInet-based app usually does not need to configure a proxy (but certain can if needed) if the user has configured a proxy in Windows configuration.